# mysql_query -> mysql_fetch_array only returning last input row

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a mysql_query and mysql_fetch_array in order to return an array of values to use in a foreach loop.

For some reason only the last inputted row is returned by the query when I print_r the array that is returned.

What I am doing is:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from table_name;");
$returned_array = mysql_fetch_array($query);
print_r($returned_array)
```

Say for example there are 4 values in the table (a, b, c, d), only the last would be returned to me, so what I see is: `Array ( [0] => d )`.
How do I go about fixing this or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What you should see is an `E_DEPRECATED` notice: please don't use `mysql_*`, the extension has been deprecated years ago. Learn to use `PDO` or `mysqli_*` instead (the replacement extensions)

Comment: As @EliasVanOotegem said mysql_* are deprecated and your code had some typo `$returned_array - mysql_fetch_array($query);` instead of `=` you are using `-`

Comment: normally you'd put it in a while loop and it'll fetch rows until it runs out

Comment: You don't have an ORDER BY clause so you cannot assume any order. Since you only fetch one row, it can be any arbitrary row—not even a random row!

Comment: When I tried to use mysqli it came up with an error such as follows (stripped due to work):Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /file Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, integer given in /file

Comment: You can't just replace all mysql_* with mysqli_*. It doesn't work that way. Read the docs, http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to fetch all the record

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from table_name");
while($returned_array = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
/*.......*/
}
```

Comment: if it worked please mark as right so that other can get answer without difficulty

Comment: good, but what this ; means in ("SELECT * from table_name;");

Comment: pls be fair, since all users will get this as his/her references in the future.

Comment: @vivek It's not "wrong" to put a semicolon at the end of the SQL statement, it's just not how most people do it.

Comment: Also mysql_* is deprecated? Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a while loop. `fetch_array` returns only one row.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from table_name;");
while( $returned_array = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
print_r($returned_array); }
```

Btw **use** `mysqli`. And as Álvaro G. Vicario told use an `ORDER BY` clause.

Typical `mysqli` example:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

$query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * from table_name;");
while( $returned_array = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
print_r($returned_array); }
```

Comment: Cheers, that's perfect!

Comment: @swiftie821 check this mysqli example

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use mysql_fetch_assoc() function to fetch a result row as an associative array.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from table_name");
while($returned_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
     //use your data for each row here like this: echo $returned_array['ID'];
}
```